# How to get hh:mm:ss.uuuuuu timestamp in c++?

Tags: c++, time, c++-chrono

I'm looking to print `hh:mm:ss.uuuuuu` timestamps in C++. It seems like I need to use the chrono library and `std::chrono::use high_resolution_clock::now()`?

I'm unsure how to proceed from here however.

Comment: What is `uuuuuu` milliseconds? Microseconds?

Comment: @JonnyHenly `u` in time formats generally represents microseconds.  Additionally, microseconds would imply 6 digits of precision, which matches the specified `uuuuuu`.

Answer (score 2):

This is easily accomplished with this [C++20 chrono preview library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) which works with C++11/14/17:

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    cout << format("%T", floor<microseconds>(system_clock::now())) << '\n';
}
```

Just output for me:

```
19:31:54.033196
```

This will port to C++20 by:

- Drop `#include "date/date.h"`
- Drop `using namespace date;`
- Change `"%T"` to `"{:%T}"`

This is a header-only, open-source library.

The output is UTC.  If you need local time, that is available too, but the library is not header-only.  It is at the same link and would be used like this:

```
#include "date/tz.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    zoned_time zt{current_zone(), floor<microseconds>(system_clock::now()))};
    cout << format("%T", zt) << '\n';
}
```

The above syntax uses C++17.  If you're using C++11 or 14 change `zoned_time` to `zoned_time<microseconds>`.

[Some installation is required for the tz.h library.](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#Installation)